# Prevent NCurses C++ Library From Creating Sub-Window

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, prompt, ncurses, curses

I want to prevent the C++ ncurses library from creating its own sub-window when activated. Whenever you use `initscr()` with ncurses, it creates its own sub-window (text area in terminal). Not using `initscr()` and proceeding to use ncurses will lead to a segmentation fault. Does anyone know how to use ncurses without it creating its own sub-window?

In my case I am using ncurses to do a "selection prompt" where options are displayed, and the user can go though them with arrow keys until the find one they want (enter key twice to select).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>

std::string prompt(const std::vector<std::string> &options, const std::string &message)
{
    // * NCURSES init
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    noecho();

    int choice;
    int highlight = 0;
    int num_options = options.size();

    while (true)
    {
        // * Clear line
        int y, x;
        getyx(stdscr, y, x);
        move(y, 0);
        clrtoeol();

        // * Display options
        printw("%s: ", (message).c_str());
        for (int i = 0; i < num_options; ++i)
        {
            if (i == highlight)
                attron(A_REVERSE);

            printw("%s ", options[i].c_str());
            attroff(A_REVERSE);
        }

        // * Get user input
        choice = getch();

        // * Decoding selection
        switch (choice)
        {
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            highlight = (highlight - 1 + num_options) % num_options;
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            highlight = (highlight + 1) % num_options;
            break;
        case '\n':
            refresh();
            getch();
            endwin();
            printf("\n");
            return options[highlight];
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    // * NCURSES cleanup
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    prompt({"agree", "disagree"}, "choose one");
    std::cout << "Hello World #2\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code, you will notice that in the ncurses sub window, only the stuff in the prompt function will appear. After selection, you will see the first message ("Hello World"), then a blank line where the prompt should be, then the second message ("Hello World #2").

Comment: Can you use `filter()`, so ncurses is in single line mode?

Comment: I tried using `filter()` by placing it directly before `initscr()`, but all that seems to do is move the prompt down a little... issue still persists.

Comment: Since `filter()` didn't work, Thomas Dickey (the author of **ncurses**) indicates that ncurses doesn't work the way you want it to.  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2008-07/msg00002.html

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think I might just have to code my own user-interface for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ncurses does not work without using it's own sub-window.